# Accidentally removed boot partition for Windows. How can I recover?

Tags: windows, bootloader, boot-partition, bootmgr

While doing some operation on Ubuntu I accidentally removed boot partition for Windows and now I can’t run Windows again and was unable to run the recovery for Windows 10.

Here’s what I have tried:

- I have made a a bootable USB flash drive for Windows and tried to run Windows reset and all other options to reinstall Windows.
- I have tried some commands for `/fixmgr` `/fixboot` and all and nothing works.

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Sorry to hear about this. What version of Windows are you using? You originally tagged this as Windows 10 and Windows 8; but which exact version are you dealing with?

Comment: What commands did you use that removed the boot partition for Windows? As in, can you reverse them?

Comment: Also, is the disk configured as MBR (Master Boot Record) or GPT (GUID Partition Table)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i didn't used any command. I was seeing something in gui and doing some work with partitions and accidentally removed it

Comment: @CBHacking disk is configured as MBR

Comment: @Akshay There is [Accidentally Deleted Boot Partition in Windows 10 – How to Recover?](https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/accidentally-deleted-boot-partition-windows-10.html) but I don't know if the suggested software is free. Read all the way to the end before trying anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, did you overwrite the deleted partition, or did you just delete it? If you simply deleted it, you may be able to simply re-create the partition and not even need to re-format it. The trick would be to modify the partition table (the metadata at the start of the disk that lists the partition types, and where each one starts and ends); I don't know of a tool to do this but I'm sure it exists, or in extremis you could do it with a hex editor. If you create a new partition normally, it might overwrite volume metadata at the start of the partition, which would be undesirable although still possibly recoverable.

If you need to re-create the boot partition, here's one approach. On recent versions (and GPT disks), Windows uses an EFI System Partition for boot. You can manually re-create one of the appropriate size (using partition tools from either Windows or Linux boot media), and then clone the data from another machine running the same Windows OS. The Linux command `dd`, available in pretty much any install or live media, can clone an image and restore it; it's got a pretty arcane syntax but the basic command would be something like `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/flashdrive/boot_partition_image bs=4M` to clone the partition from another computer's working disk and then `dd if=/media/flashdrive/boot_partition_image of=/dev/sda1 bs=4M` to restore it on your computer (double-check that the device names are correct; you don't want to accidentally overwrite data that you need). Note that this might copy some per-machine metadata as well - I'm not sure where all of that is stored - but since your copy of any such metadata is probably now lost anyhow. Also note that, unless you grab the system partition from another Windows+Linux disk configured the same way yours was, you risk making Linux unbootable instead (until repaired); I'm not actually sure what the Ubuntu installer does for dual-boot configurations if you just accept the defaults.

Comment: I tried it but this doesn't worked. Anyway thanx for the help @CBHacking